# magento installation on localhost giving creating admin account error

Tags: php, magento, authentication

I have installed magento on localhost successfully but one small problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to create an admin account it is showing message "Only registered domain accounts are allowed" when I entered my email address. Can anyone help me ?

We are facing this problem in the actual site also when the customer buys some product from our site and come back to buy another product magento shows the same message even when person click on forgot password it shows same message again.

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Usually while installation of Magento, it is not required to get the domain accounts registered.For localhost, it accepts any valid email ID.

But since your are facing an issue, Check, While installation of Magento (I am using version 1.9.0.1), In your database connection phase:

1) Select Drop Down option FILE SYSTEM for save session data.

2) Enable Charts should be checked.

3) Base URL must have your localhost path to magento.

4) Admin path should be : admin.

Comment: It is not accepting base URL as localhost/head hence i have selected skip base url validation before next step. Rest all options are same as u told me.

Comment: showing message "The URL "http://localhost/head" is invalid.
        Response from server isn't valid."

Comment: It should be 'http://localhost/Your_magento_folder_name'. Still if it doesnt work, Try with your system's IP address, i.e. Set your base URL as 'http://Your_IP Address/Your_magento_folder_name'.

Comment: 'Head' is the name of folder where magento is place and my local ip address is 192.168.1.12 and when i try to use this then i got message shown below:         The URL "http://192.168.1.12/head/" is not accessible.
        Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message

Comment: Run ur installation wizard using http://192.168.1.12:8888/head/index.php/install/wizard/              8888 is my apache port number.You have to find out yours. And then put Base URL as 192.168.1.12:8888/head

Comment: still showing the same msg...        The URL "http://192.168.1.12:80/head/" is not accessible.
        Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message

Comment: which server u r using? wamp? lamp? mamp? which one?

Comment: I m using Xampp and i have used http.

Comment: It is not a tricky thing to install magento but dont know why such issue is arising. It is simple to save the  magento(head) folder to xampp/htdocs/ then just run its installation wizard using localhopst or ip address.Simple thing but ur issue is not getting solved.

Comment: You are rite.. even i have not observed this issue ever.. this is the first time i have got this issue and m really struggling with this... please give me some more idea....if u can...thanks...even i have tried changing folder also but still getting stuck...

Comment: check [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp)

Comment: Try by changing the port number for apache. Make it 8888 and try.Sometimes it happen the port number doesnt works fine.